# Piping parts of a file to a command that requires multiple inputs

Tags: unix, pipe

Often when doing some things in my Unix shell, I would like to pipe a part of one file to a particular command, such as:

```
cut -f1 file1 | perl -pe 's/foo/bar/'
```

I like this because it means I don't have to have a whole other file just for column 1 of `file1`.

Though, I run into problems when I want to do a command that takes in multiple sets of input such as `join` . I wish I could do something like:

```
join (cut -f1 file1) (cut -f1 file2)
```

Is there some way to do this nicely without creating unnecessary files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps this:

```
join <(cut -f1 file1) <(cut -f1 file2)
```

That assumes you're using `bash` as a shell, though...

Answer (score 3):

You're using a pipe to redirect to stdin; since there's only one stdin, you can only do one pipe this way.  If you want more pipes, you'd need to use named pipes (aka fifos)

i.e.

```
mkfifo pipe1 pipe2
cut -f1 file1 > pipe1 &
cut -f1 file2 > pipe2 &
join pipe1 pipe2
```

The cut commands will block until the join starts reading their output, since the pipes aren't real files that can contain data; just names to allow multiple pipes.

Comment: do you have to remove pipe1 and pipe2 afterwards?

Comment: You can just rm them if you don't need them anymore; otherwise they would persist and you could use them for other commands.

Comment: This is probably the better solution for the general case

Answer (score 0):

You can instead use awk to get similar output:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[NR]=$1; next} {print a[FNR], $1}' file1 file2
```